# Laravel 8 - Show a customised 404 blade page, when a Controller does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

When there is no controller **action** , then it can be checked as

```
if(! method_exists($controller, $action)) {
    return 404;
}
```

But when there is **no** *Controller*, I am getting this error

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [\App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController] does not exist.
```

But, is it possible to show a ***custom 404 blade***  page instead?

Comment: You are on development environment , if you set `APP_DEBUG=true` to `APP_DEBUG=false` on the `.env` then you won't see any exception error

Comment: @Droid Thanks. But, now I am getting `500| Server Error`. But what I want is either show a `return view` page (without changing the default pages of Laravel error blade files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Droid pointed out,

- set `APP_DEBUG=false` in the `.env` file.
- Then use `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors` in command prompt (where the project is stored). All the Laravel designed error pages (40x,50x, etc.) will be shown.
- In here, customise these pages as per your requirement.

From then, irrespective of any error message, whether you mess up with your URL or something happens on the server side, you will see your customized error pages.

Comment: Great. It is working. But, what if I want to test the same in test environment (i.e Localhost)?

Comment: You can. You may need to handle the respective exceptions first. And to be on the safe side, ALWAYS set `APP_DEBUG` to false

Answer (score 3):

So all of the default Laravel errors pages can be found `./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/views`

You can run this command to publish the error view pages yourself and customize them.
`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors`
Then they will be located
`./resources/views/errors`

Also, you should use `abort(404)` instead of returning 404. This will fire the `render` in your `App\Exceptions\Handler` If you did not overwrite this method it will use the Laravel default. But to overwrite you could do

```
app/Exceptions/Handler.php

public function render($request, Throwable $exception)

{
    $response = parent::render($request, $exception);

    if ($response->status() === 404) {
        // return something custom
    }

    return $response;
}
```

You can follow the documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#custom-http-error-pages. Hope this helps!

Comment: Syntax error, should be if ($response->status() === 404)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Route::any('/', function () {
    //
});

for unknown controller and make a view 


[documentation][1] :https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing
```

Answer (score 1):

you can customise `404` error by `publishing` laravel errors page and customise that

#### Run

```php
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors
```

it be publish all the errors page laravel have in `views/errors` dir

ref link

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#http-exceptions

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a folder called **errors** in your views folder. Then create another view called **404.blade.php** but inside errors folder. Laravel will understand that the 404 blade file simply represents the page where you want to redirect when people are getting 404 exception.

So after that you can customize 404 blade file as you wish and whenever you get 404 error that page will show up

Answer (score 1):

`4XX` response status codes represent "Client errors". `404 Not Found` should be thrown when the server can not find the requested resource.

On the other hand, `5XX` response status codes represent "Server errors". `500 Internal Server Error` means the server has encountered a situation it doesn't know how to handle.

The error you are getting is actually a server error.

It has nothing to do with the client and therefore, it should not be throwing `404 Not Found`.

So instead, you can just create the controller and do `abort(404);` inside the controller method like so:

```php
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        abort(404);
    }
}
```

Resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status